# Nested Combo Menus in PySimpleGui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm looking for a drop down menu system to help control the flow for a variety of locations.

The structure would look like this

```
[location[rack 1,[Shelf 1, [Bin A, Bin B, Bin C, Bin D, Bin E]
                 Shelf 2, [Locations...]
                 Shelf 3, [Locations...]
                 Shelf 4, [Locations...]]
        rack 2,[so on] 
...
]]
```

I looked into Menus but that will force to the top of the window regardless of placement in the layout. I tried to throw the menu code (basically what you see above) as a combo and it just displayed all as one.

To get to the point of the question: Is there a way to do nested combo menus in pysimplegui, or do I need to do something else. And if so, what should should I be looking at for a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ButtonMenu` element, you can add "keys" to make menu items unique or as another way of identifying a menu item than the text shown. The key is added to the text portion by placing :: after the text.

`Menu Item::key`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

menu_def = ['Location',
    [
        'Rack 1',
            [
                'Shelf 1', ['Bin A::11', 'Bin B::11'],
                'Shelf 2', ['Bin A::12', 'Bin B::12'],
            ],
        'Rack 2',
            [
                'Shelf 1', ['Bin A::21', 'Bin B::21'],
                'Shelf 2', ['Bin A::22', 'Bin B::22'],
            ],
    ]
]

layout = [[sg.ButtonMenu('Location', menu_def=menu_def, key='Button_Menu')]]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Button_Menu':
        print(values[event])

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at this later last night and was a bit confused by it. This makes much more sense now. Thank you again.

Comment: Oooo.... that's tasty!  Never thought about using a ButtonMenu like a Combo/DropDown.  This is a great & creative idea, and doesn't need anything special outside the normal PySimpleGUI calls.